# How do I make a java class that inherits from another one which is loading an fxml file

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a custom interface that I created in scene builder and I want to reuse it in a variation created with a child class.  The problem seems to be that it won't inherit methods marked with @FXML.  Is there any way to extend a class that loads fxml instead of copying the entire class?

Example Parent Class:

```
public class Browser extends StackPane implements Initializable {

public Browser() {
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/Browser.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
fxmlLoader.setController(this);
try {
fxmlLoader.load();
} catch (IOException exception) {
throw new RuntimeException(exception);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}

// Adds a new tab.
@FXML
private void addTab(ActionEvent event) {
    BrowserTab tab = new BrowserTab();
    tab.getEngine().load(initialTab.getAddress());
    if (tabs.getTabs().size() >= TABMAX + 1) {
        BaseApp.showNotify("You may open a maximum of " + TABMAX + " tabs.");
    } else {
        tabs.getTabs().add(tabs.getTabs().size() - 1, tab.tab);
    }
}
}
```

Example Child Class:

```
public class AdBrowser extends Browser {

public AdBrowser() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/AdBrowser.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}

}
```

When I try to run the program instantiating the child class I get and error saying Controller method "addTab" not found.

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't inherit"? What is your *specific* problem?

Comment: I have seen this problem before when I forgot to put a method referenced in the fxml file into the controller class.  The problem here is that the controller method  is in the parent class which is a controller class but doesn't seem to be inherited by the child class.

Comment: I have no experience at all with fxml, but you could try broadening the access permissions to that method, e.g. to protected. If that does the trick, then you can investigate whether this kind of access restriction is by design, an accident, or perhaps even configurable.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Write it up as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer.*

I have no experience at all with fxml, but you could try broadening the access permissions to that method, e.g. from `private` to `protected`.

Code outside the class defining a `private` method is usually not allowed to call that method. Some frameworks circumvent these restrictions, and perhaps javafx is among them. But even these frameworks might and often will distinguish based on what access privileges a given method has.

One reason behind this is that a private method name should never cause a clash: you can have two private methods of the same name in base class and derived class, and neither knows of the other. They [will not override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) one another. As far as the derived class is concerned, the method in the parent class simply does not exist. Since this is a reasonable working principle, it makes sense for frameworks to follow this as well, even if circumvented access restrictions would allow them to act otherwise.

Comment: I completely forgot about this.  Sometimes it just takes a fresh eye to see what is right in front of you.